# Optimize SQL Server cache

Tags: sql-server, caching, query-optimization

**Hi everyone,**

I have a database with thousands of triggers & stored procédures.
So my clients have a big problem , every day some of object are cleared from cache and then some flow of my application take some time (30, 40 seconds) the first time they exec and less than a second the next time. but if they wait for like 2-3h then objects are cleared and my flow are slow.

So my question is : Is there a way to force SQL Server to cache some object because he's very long to reload those objects. I have a lot of RAM (30 Giga available so i think i can cache a lot of objects)

Thank you by advance for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> s there a way to force SQL Server to cache some object because he's very long to reload those objects

In Summary,No.But if you are on SQLServer 2012, you can use InMemory OLTP objects though

hope below helps you in dealing with memory issues

> I have a lot of RAM (30 Giga available so i think i can cache a lot of objects)

Even though you have enough RAM,amount of cache that Buffer pool can use will depend on MAX Server Memory configuration ,so i assume that you have set it correctly

Once you have set that value correctly,you must be aware that ,this Cache will be used for many things ,but below are the main ones

1.Pages
2.Execution plan cache

If you have lot of databases in that server and there are many queries running, your 30GB may not be enough..

using below query, you can identify,which database is using more memory

```
SELECT COUNT(*) *8  AS  memoryusedKB
    ,CASE database_id   
        WHEN 32767 THEN 'ResourceDb'   
        ELSE db_name(database_id)   
        END AS database_name  
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors  
GROUP BY DB_NAME(database_id) ,database_id  
ORDER BY memoryused DESC;
```

if you want segregate that by object,you can do that too

```
SELECT COUNT(*)AS cached_pages_count   
    ,name ,index_id   
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors AS bd   
    INNER JOIN   
    (  
        SELECT object_name(object_id) AS name   
            ,index_id ,allocation_unit_id  
        FROM sys.allocation_units AS au  
            INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p   
                ON au.container_id = p.hobt_id   
                    AND (au.type = 1 OR au.type = 3)  
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT object_name(object_id) AS name     
            ,index_id, allocation_unit_id  
        FROM sys.allocation_units AS au  
            INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p   
                ON au.container_id = p.partition_id   
                    AND au.type = 2  
    ) AS obj   
        ON bd.allocation_unit_id = obj.allocation_unit_id  
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()  
GROUP BY name, index_id   
ORDER BY cached_pages_count DESC;
```

Now that you know,which database is consuming more memory  , you can look at which  memory pool is consuming more memory

```
select type,sum(pages_kb)*128 as memoryusedMB 
from sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
group by type
```

At this point of time, you have full idea of how  memory is used in your Server

so you can try to further eliminate wastage from below script of Kimberely Tripp,which deletes cache entries from Database for Adhoc plans  :[Plan cache and optimizing for adhoc workloads](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-and-optimizing-for-adhoc-workloads/)

Below script gives you the memory usage by single object plans, you can see if that is acceptable to you.checking the same link, you will have a script to delete those entries as well

```
SELECT objtype AS [CacheType],
    COUNT_BIG(*) AS [Total Plans],
    SUM(CAST(size_in_bytes AS DECIMAL(18, 2))) / 1024 / 1024 AS [Total MBs],
    AVG(usecounts) AS [Avg Use Count],
    SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN usecounts = 1 THEN size_in_bytes
        ELSE 0
        END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2))) / 1024 / 1024 AS [Total MBs – USE Count 1],
    SUM(CASE WHEN usecounts = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END) AS [Total Plans – USE Count 1]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
GROUP BY objtype
ORDER BY [Total MBs – USE Count 1] DESC
```

Further you can use lock pages in memory,which forces sql server to keep pages in Memory .But i won't go with it.You can read it here for more info though

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/great-sql-server-debates-lock-pages-in-memory/